# sas append doesn't work in macro

Tags: sas

Hi I have a question about the append commend in SAS,

I tried

```
PROC APPEND BASE=SASUSER.mitsumjan12lag1
            DATA=SASUSER.mitsumjan12lag2;
RUN;
```

and it worked.  But when I'm trying the same thing in a macro like below, it doesn't work.

```
%macro combineData(month=,part,datamonth=,datapart=);
  PROC APPEND BASE=SASUSER.mitsum&month.lag&part
              DATA=SASUSER.mitsum&datamonth.lag&datapart;
  RUN; 
%mend combineData;
%combineData(month=jan12,part=1,datamonth=jan12,datapart=2);
```

Can anyone help me with it? Thank you.

Comment: It looks okay to me; In what way did it not work?  If you got a SAS error message, add that to your question.  It may be that you need to strip blanks from your macro variable references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that strikes me is that you are missing a `=` after `part` in

```
%macro combineData(month=,part,datamonth=,datapart=);
```

Positional parameters (those without `=`) must be put before the keyword parameters (those with `=`).
Just change the `part` parameter into keyword parameter (add `=` after it) like this:

```
%macro combineData(month=,part=,datamonth=,datapart=);
```

or put it on first place, like this:

```
%macro combineData(part, month=,datamonth=,datapart=);
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess next time, I will check the code more carefully